# Date and DateTime in Spotfire 7.x used with sdcGetData function parameters

Tags: r, spotfire, terr

does anyone know how to use Date / DateTime Spotfire types as parameters for `sdcGetData` in R?

I'm trying to access data in our Spotfire library using the `SpotfireData` library availble in TERR. I follow the instructions in the documentation [here](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise-runtime-for-R/4.0.2/doc/html/Language_Reference/SpotfireData/sdcConnect.html). I have an information-link I'm trying retrieve data from which has two prompts defined (Product, StartDate). When I run `sdcGetInfo` I get the following.

```
Spotfire data connection info
  server: http://OURSPOTFIRESERVER/spotfire
  path: /INFOLINKPATH
  1 view

Spotfire data connection view: "INFOLINKPATH"
  Parameters:
       Name DataType Required AllowMultipleValues IsRangeValues
1 StartDate     Date     TRUE                TRUE          TRUE
2   Product   String     TRUE                TRUE         FALSE
```

I then try to query data with

```
df <- sdcGetData(conn, "/INFOLINKPATH", Product = "ABCD", StartDate = c(as.POSIXct("2018-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2018-06-01")))
```

Which does not work and returns

```
Error in sdcHttp(conn, url, body = NULL, headers = headers, sendCooki : http err
or: status=500
```

Now I tried several things with the data including `as.Date`, using strings, `as.POSIXlt`, adding timezone information. I've also tried not using `RANGE` type prompt and instead single value but still get 500 error. If I remove the date as a prompt it works and returns data. Spotfire does not like my dates used as parameters but I cannot figure out why.